# Restrictions on etcd in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I know that the storage used by Kubernetes in GKE is fully managed and not exposed ([source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kubernetes-users/6BLcAQAvPCU/cspFZt3eBgAJ)). But I wanted to know if there is any limitation/restriction on the storage size. I couldn't find any link which clarifies this part.

For example, I am using GKE to run small jobs. Should I create a batch job which regularly deletes the old job information or not bother about deleting them at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GKE job is running, and once the job is completed, the API will not [delete the job](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/jobs). Jobs are not deleted but they are `terminated`.

When a job is `terminated`, it means that it is no longer running but you can [still access its log files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup), and view its status. A `terminated` job will not consume too many resources.

You may keep the `terminated` jobs, if you would like to keep a record of the logs.

If retaining the logs has no benefit in your use case, then you may delete the old jobs.

Lastly, to answer your question, yes there is a storage limit on etcd in GKE. The limit on the etcd datastore is of a few GB.

Note that if the etcd datastore hits its storage limit, your application effectively becomes unavailable. This means that it would be a good idea to delete the jobs to make sure that the etcd storage limit is not reached.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am aware of what you have posted. My question was that, is there any restriction on the size of data stored in the managed etcd in GKE, since the job details will be stored in etcd? If there is none, then I wouldn't bother with deleting the old completed jobs.

Comment: Thank you. So, it looks like I have to write a batch job which deletes the old jobs. Could you please provide with links to documentation where this limitation of storage limit in GKE etcd is mentioned? It would be good to know the actual size limit.

Comment: The etcd storage limit is not a value that is set in stone. The size limit is set differently as specified by the Kubernetes version or the vendor. And the storage size may change in the future. For more information on the etcd storage size, you may read through [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/etcd-dev/WaUc_mPbmVI).

Comment: What you have said makes sense i.e. there would be some limit on the storage of etcd. But there is no official documentation from Google which mentions this. I am not looking for a definite value, even a range would have been fine. This would have been helpful in deciding the frequency with which I can clear old job entries. The link that you have given is not related to GKE but etcd in general. I am not sure if GKE backs up old job details in some other DB so that we don't hit the etcd storage limit(just a guess) But for lack of a better answer, I will go ahead & accept this answer. Thank you

Comment: The etcd storage is a of a few GB. This means that it is between 3GB and 6GB. But it shouldn't be taken at face value as it depends on the vendor, the Kubernetes version, and it may change in the future.